# How to take all items defined by IN clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table Events in mysql which contains dates and event types as shown below:

```
Date    Event
1.11.2017   A
1.11.2017   B
1.11.2017   C
1.11.2017   D
2.11.2017   B
2.11.2017   C
2.11.2017   D
3.11.2017   A
3.11.2017   C
3.11.2017   E
4.11.2017   A
4.11.2017   B
4.11.2017   D
```

I want to find out the dates which include events A and B. In the example above this would be 1.11.2017 and 4.11.2017.
I tried with IN clause

```
select distinct Date from Events 
    where Event in ('A', 'B')
```

but this clause returns rows where any of the conditional items is present (A or B).

How can I implement such kind of IN clause where all listed conditions have to be included?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I used a subquery to count the occurrences of A and B. This solutions assumes there is never more than one A or B per day.

```
SELECT DISTINCT e1.eventDate
FROM events e1
JOIN (SELECT eventDate, count(*)  count 
      FROM events 
      WHERE type IN ('A', 'B')
      GROUP BY eventDate) as e2 ON e2.eventDate = e1.eventDate
WHERE e2.count > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select `Date` from Events
where Event in ('A', 'B')
group by `Date`
having count(*) = 2
```

It doesn't require `JOIN`, thus has better performance.